# How to add an app to Launchpad with application type "SAPUI5-Fiori-App"?

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-gui

I made an app and added this one to Launchpad with application type "SAPUI5-Fiori-App using LPD_CUST". Now I was taught, that this is application type deprecated and I shall use application type "SAPUI5-Fiori-App".

I tried to do it and tried to copy the necessary entries from an app, that already has these settings, but I cannot copy those for my application because I dont know what to fill into the fields "URL" and "ID".

I suppose the field "URL" needs a SICF-service with path "/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/". But for my namespace there is no service generated wihtin that path. So I created this service manually. But I don't know if this is the correct way. I just gave it a try.

And the field "ID" has some entry like com.customersname.APPNAME. But I have no clue where I can find this information.

Furhtermore I cannot find an manual or instruction in the internet for adding an app to LPD with this application type. I can only find some information for application type "SAPUI5-Fiori-App using LPD_CUST".

I hope somebody can help me and give me a hint what to do or where I can find a manual for my case.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the service (sicf node) should be automatically created when you deploy an Application to your Gateway. (Bsp-Application). The only thing you normally need to do ist activate the SICF node.

Answer (score 0):

This can be also done using /n/ui2/flpd_conf.
And this path "/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/" in SICF will be created only after deploying your app.

Another tip I give is to fill up your custom request in SU3 before configuring the fiori lauchpad, so your catalog and group will be attached to your request automatically when click saving. Go to SU3, parameter tab and add these two parameters.
/UI2/WD_TRKORR_CONF_CONF value S4DKxxxxxx.
/UI2/WD_TRKORR_CONF_CUST value S4DKxxxxxx.